# I keep getting errors when working on this query. The closest I think I got, still returned ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle-apex, ora-00933

I am learning SQL and can not figure out what I am doing wrong in my code.

```
Select robot, city, country, count(sponsor.sponsor)
    From robot join sponsor on robot.robotid = sponsor.robotid
        Group by robotid
Where country not in ('United States');
```

I am supposed to find all robots not from the US and how many sponsors they have. I have figured out how to get only the international robots from the robot table and the total number of sponsors each robotID has in the sponsor table but can not figure out how to join them. If it helps the pk for both tables is robotID but that value should not be returned in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with the query.  Three that are obvious:

- The `select` columns are not compatible with the `group by` columns.
- The `where` clause is misplaced.
- `robotid` is ambiguous

One could guess that you intend:

```
Select r.robot, city, country, count(*)
From robot r join
     sponsor s
     on r.robotid = s.robotid
where country not in ('United States')
group by r.robot, city, country;
```

This is just a guess.  It should fix the syntax problems, but it may not be what you want.  Why not?  You have not explained your problem, provided sample data, or desired results.

Comment: Thank you for the help with the little info I provided. I am not really used to asking for help online so I tried to mimic how I saw some other questions asked, I guess I did it poorly.

Answer (score -1):

Check this out.

```
Select robot, city, country, count(sponsor.sponsor)
From robot join sponsor on robot.robotid = sponsor.robotid
Where country not in ('United States')
Group by robotid;
```

Comment: When I try that I get ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined. When I try Group by sponsor.robotid or robot.robotid I get ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression.

Comment: @LPM: Well, that answer answers the original problem you asked for, which was caused by a misplaced `GROUP BY` clause. So you should accept this answer and post a new question if you have further problems. But **be sure** to provide a [example] in the new question. I.e. provide the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. Along with the query you're having the problems with, of course.

Comment: Select robot.robot, robot.city,robot.country, count(sponsor.sponsor)
          From robot join sponsor on robot.robotid = sponsor.robotid
          Where robot.country not in ('United States')
          Group by robotid;